# how to determine object acess for all users

Tags: apex

In apex how can I build a list of Users that have access to an object without knowing specific profile/permission set names?

UPDATE:

here's what I'm currently working with and its coming back with 0 rows:

```
list<PermissionSetAssignment> pms = [SELECT Assignee.Name, PermissionSet.Id, PermissionSet.isOwnedByProfile, PermissionSet.Profile.Name, PermissionSet.Label
        FROM PermissionSetAssignment
        WHERE PermissionSetId
        IN (SELECT ParentId
        FROM ObjectPermissions
        WHERE SObjectType = 'Custom_Obj__c' AND PermissionsRead = true)];
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah I think I got it:

```
list<PermissionSetAssignment> pms = [SELECT Assignee.Name,Assignee.id, PermissionSet.Id, PermissionSet.isOwnedByProfile, PermissionSet.Profile.Name, PermissionSet.Label
        FROM PermissionSetAssignment
        WHERE PermissionSetId
        IN (SELECT ParentId
        FROM ObjectPermissions
        WHERE SObjectType = 'Custom_Obj__c' AND PermissionsRead = true)];
```

**NOTE:** If your customObj is in a package it needs the namespace (I was missing this...)

After this I just build a set of User IDs based on the assignee.id and query for the Users. Seems to be working correctly so far but I'll continue to test and update this if I find any issues.

This post was very helpful:
http://blogs.developerforce.com/engineering/2012/06/using-soql-to-determine-your-users-permissions-2.html

Answer (score 1):

This is metadata that isn't accessible directly through Apex Code. However, you can use a tool like [Etherios EasyDescribe](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000018leZEAQ), [Object Metadata Snapshot Tool](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003Ih3aEAC), or other services that can translate metadata to simple records that can be queried. Once described, you can then query them in normal Apex Code, just like any other object. * *Note, I am not affiliated with either tool linked here, nor do I specifically condone the use of any one tool over another.*

Comment: I have a feeling that ObjectPermissions should be able to do this...